# ESP32 GPIO State at reset/after reset

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, esp32, reset

Im trying to understand in what state the gpio pins of the microcontroller will be when it will power up or when I flash new code. The mcu on both cases I assume will be at reset?

The [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s2_datasheet_en.pdf) at page 44 has a IO_MUX with columns [At Reset | After Reset]. But I can't figure out what ie, oe means for the state of the GPIO.

Also At Reset is self explanatory but what After Reset means? It's the default value of the gpio in case I haven't assign it?

I am driving relays on the gpios and I don't want to accidentally turn them on.

FYI the relays are connected to GPIO33, GPIO34

Comment: don't know the difference between "at reset" and "after reset" but GPIO33 and GPIO34 have oe=0 for both. Footnote says oe=output enable. So output enable=0. Output is disabled.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah i saw that but does that help me to know if it will be 3v3 or 0v?

Comment: it won't be enabled to output anything. So that depends on whether you wired it to 3v3 or 0v. Which one would it be if the microcontroller suddenly disappeared?

Comment: @user253751 so I can assume it's like it's floating during reset?

Comment: yes? output disabled means it's floating. Note that I also saw that some GPIO pins are "strapping pins" that have internal pull-up and pull-down during reset. But the ones you are using are not.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah i don't think ill mess with the strapping pins. If it's floating it is good enough for me. I don't want it to be pulled-down in my case.

Comment: I guess you have a module with a relay and a control circuit, not a plain relay. I guess the module has a pull-up or pull-down resistor. For Espressif MCUs there is a time after reset when the bootloaders runs and sets some pins HIGH based on some configuration

Comment: @Juraj the pin will drive an optocoupler that will drive a bjt transistor that will activate the relay… Ill post the schematic later with some modifications i have in mind